# parsing JSON url in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json data that I want to get it from my json array so that I can display the data on my php form. Here is my json object:

```
{
"response": {
    "result": {
        "Contacts": {
            "row": [
                {
                    "no": "1",
                    "fl": [
                        {
                            "val": "CONTACTID",
                            "content": "144120000000079041"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "First Name",
                            "content": "Tata"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Last Name",
                            "content": "Nyerere"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Email",
                            "content": "nyereredaniel@gmail.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Account Name",
                            "content": "null"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Phone",
                            "content": "null"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Mobile",
                            "content": "null"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "no": "2",
                    "fl": [
                        {
                            "val": "CONTACTID",
                            "content": "144120000000069001"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "First Name",
                            "content": "null"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Last Name",
                            "content": "DANIEL NYERERE"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Email",
                            "content": "nyereredaniel@hotmail.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Account Name",
                            "content": "null"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Phone",
                            "content": "null"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Mobile",
                            "content": "null"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "no": "3",
                    "fl": [
                        {
                            "val": "CONTACTID",
                            "content": "144120000000065068"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "First Name",
                            "content": "null"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Last Name",
                            "content": "Lawrence"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Email",
                            "content": "support@zohosupport.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "ACCOUNTID",
                            "content": "144120000000065066"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Account Name",
                            "content": "Zoho"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Phone",
                            "content": "1 888 900 9646"
                        },
                        {
                            "val": "Mobile",
                            "content": "null"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "uri": "/api/json/contacts/getrecords"
}
}
```

I need to display those data on my php form , and here is the sample i have tried but i'm stuck with it:`

```
<?php
$url = "my url";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($json, true);
$response = $json['response'];
$result = $response['result'];
$contact = $result['Contacts'];
$data = $contact['row'];
$name = $dat[0];
echo "Contact name: " . $name;
?>
```

I want to display the values of CONTACTID ,First Name ,Last Name ,Email into my php form 
Anyone who can assist on that ,will appreciate a lot

Comment: well, where's your form? The form is in HTML actually, php can be used only to generate it.
See  -- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp -- 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp -- http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple way, i made a helper function to extract value from array. Look at this example:

```
<?php
$url      = "my url";
$json     = file_get_contents($url);
$json     = json_decode($json, true);
$response = $json['response'];
$result   = $response['result'];
$contact  = $result['Contacts'];
$data     = $contact['row'];

// Helper Function
function getValByName($name, $array)
{
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        if ($row['val'] == $name) {
            return $row['content'];
        }
    }

    return '';
}

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $FirstName = getValByName('First Name', $row['fl']);
    $ContactId = getValByName('CONTACTID', $row['fl']);
    $LastName  = getValByName('Last Name', $row['fl']);
    $Email     = getValByName('Email', $row['fl']);
    $Phone     = getValByName('Phone', $row['fl']);
    $Mobile    = getValByName('Mobile', $row['fl']);

    echo $FirstName . ' ' . $LastName . '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks moein-porkamel

Comment: Glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

This PHP Code returns the Variable `$data` with all Rows as separate Data

```
<?php
$url = "my url";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($json, true);

$response = $json['response'];
$result = $response['result'];
$contacts = $result['Contacts'];
$rows = $contacts['row'];

$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $fields = $row['fl'];

    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $tmp[$field['val']] = $field['content'];
    }

    array_push($data, $tmp);
}
var_dump($data);
?>
```

The Data that will be returned is for your example JSON

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'CONTACTID' => string '144120000000079041' (length=18)
      'First Name' => string 'Tata' (length=4)
      'Last Name' => string 'Nyerere' (length=7)
      'Email' => string 'nyereredaniel@gmail.com' (length=23)
      'Account Name' => string 'null' (length=4)
      'Phone' => string 'null' (length=4)
      'Mobile' => string 'null' (length=4)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'CONTACTID' => string '144120000000069001' (length=18)
      'First Name' => string 'null' (length=4)
      'Last Name' => string 'DANIEL NYERERE' (length=14)
      'Email' => string 'nyereredaniel@hotmail.com' (length=25)
      'Account Name' => string 'null' (length=4)
      'Phone' => string 'null' (length=4)
      'Mobile' => string 'null' (length=4)
  2 => 
    array (size=8)
      'CONTACTID' => string '144120000000065068' (length=18)
      'First Name' => string 'null' (length=4)
      'Last Name' => string 'Lawrence' (length=8)
      'Email' => string 'support@zohosupport.com' (length=23)
      'ACCOUNTID' => string '144120000000065066' (length=18)
      'Account Name' => string 'Zoho' (length=4)
      'Phone' => string '1 888 900 9646' (length=14)
      'Mobile' => string 'null' (length=4)
```